# Wordpress Portfolio plugin featured image inline css

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I have wordpress based website where i use portfolio plugin. My problem is to featured image of portfolio plugin, inline css is attached to the featured image element that sets height of image to 600px which crops top of my original image.

How can i alter this 600px  to 750px ? In short, any way of changing inline element css of featured image of portfolio item on wordpress ?

element.style {
background: url(https://www.meletiorient.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/DSC_2972-.jpg) 50% 50% / cover no-repeat;
height: 600px;
}

https://www.meletiorient.com/portfolio/afghan-bukhara-single/

This is the page on live.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by changing the `custom.js` such as following

50% 0% / cover no-repeat instead of 50% 50% / cover no-repeat

```
function setBg($elem){
    $this.css({
        'background' : 'url('+src+') no-repeat 50% 50%',
        'background-size':'cover'
    });

});
```

do you think this work around can mess up something else?